# Replace functionality and UI for Windows Change password provider

Tags: credential-providers

Is there some way to replace the Windows password change functionality when a user presses 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and selects 'Change password'?

I have implemented  one `CredentialProvider` which provides additional security verification for password changes. 
It works correctly, and it works correctly when called for usage scenarios: `CPUS_LOGON`, `CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION`, `CPUS_CREDUI`. 
But it doesn't do anything for  `CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD`.

More correctly, when the user selects "change password" after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>,  `LogonUI` calls the provider and enumerates tiles (at least `PasswordResetProvider::SetUsageScenario` is called with `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO::CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD`). 
But still the standard Windows "Change password" UI is displayed. 
Is it possible somehow replace this provider with mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try on Windows 7, you should be able to switch credential.

On Windows 10, you can filter the password provider : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9c23976a-3e2b-4b71-9f19-83ee3df0848b/how-to-disable-additional-credential-providers?forum=w8itprosecurity

Or you can select the credential in GetCredentialCount method (pdwDefault).